# Do AxesLabel, PlotLabel and do the Ticks all use LabelStyle? Can one separate them?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to provide a Plot with a big and bold PlotLabel as headline for the whole picture. In order to do this, I write e.g. `LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 20], PlotLabel -> "Fig. 1B"`

However, then Bold and the character size is also used for the AxesLabel and even for the numbers at the ticks and I don't like that. It looks too fat for my purpose.

It looks like `LabelStyle` affects not only `PlotLabel`, but also `AxesLabels` and the size of numbers of symbols used for ticks (the latter seem both to be ca 15% smaller, but still I dislike them being fat and I even prefer their size to become smaller. I want to control them separately in my own way.).

**How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do AxesLabel, PlotLabel and do the ticks all use LabelStyle?***

Although the documentation suggests the answer is yes

> [image]

it seems that it is not always the case. For example, `FontSize` specified in `LabelStyle` is used in axes and ticks but it is ignored in plot label:

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x],
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Large]]
```

[image]

In case you need to apply the same styles to all label-like objects in a single place, you can use `BaseStyle` with suboptions `FontColor`, `FontSize`, `FontFamily` etc, e.g.

```
BaseStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> Large]
```

***Can one separate them?***

Relevant parts from the [Documentation >> TicksStyle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TicksStyle.html):

> - *Any outside styles not explicitly overridden by settings in `TicksStyle` will still be used.*
> - *`TicksStyle` can be used together with `LabelStyle` and has higher priority*
> - *`TicksStyle` can be used together with `AxesStyle`, and has higher priority*

And from [Documentation >> AxesStyle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AxesStyle.html):

> - *`AxesStyle` gives both the style of the axes themselves, and the
>     default style for labels and ticks. `TicksStyle` overrides
>     specifications for ticks.*

For example:

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x],
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Red, FontSize -> 24], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Gray, FontSize -> 20], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Green, FontSize -> 14]]
```

[image]